# Sonarcloud c++ docker cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

i was trying to integrate sonarcloud in my build.
I have created a free account in sonarcloud.io and added necessary steps in build pipeline.

[image]

[image]

When i ran the pipeline, i got the error

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/bw-outputs/build-wrapper-dump.json

> The process '/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SonarCloudAnalyze_ce096e50-6155-4de8-8800-4221aaeed4a1/1.20.0/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner' failed with exit code 1

Also, i tried with a .properties file.

```
sonar.projectKey=jfzlma0838_dockersample    
sonar.projectName=dockersample    
sonar.projectVersion=1.0    
sonar.sources=app    

# The build-wrapper output dir    
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-outputs    

# Encoding of the source files    
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

[full repo here (master)](https://dev.azure.com/jfzlma0838/sample/_git/dockersample)

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect both relevant code and the error message to be in the **question post** as **text**. Neither *link* to your repo nor *image* of the error message are sufficient. Please, read [ask] and update your question post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this error is that you did not run build wrapper.

Step 1. Download the Build Wrapper:

- [Build Wrapper for
  Linux](https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip)
- [Build Wrapper for
  macOS](https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-macosx-x86.zip)
- [Build Wrapper for
  Windows](https://sonarcloud.io/static/cpp/build-wrapper-win-x86.zip)

Step 2. Unzip them and push them to your repository.

Step 3. Add their path to the enviornment variable `PATH`. You can use the following PowerShell script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";
```

Note that the path of repository is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in Azure DevOps.

Step 4. Execute Build Wrapper. You can click [this document](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/languages/cfamily/#analysis-steps) for detailed steps.